# Close time must be greater than open time

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am implementing a scenario where the user will select the store open and close time. I want to ensure that close time is always greater than open time. User will select the timings as follows

Monday Open  Monday Close
8:00 AM       5:00 PM

i want to ensure the close time is logically settled right.

I am using Time input type.

My code is as follows

```
<div class="working-hours">
  <div class='row'>

    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Monday Open</label>
        <input type="time" name="mondayopentime" class="form-control monday" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Monday Close</label>
        <input type="time" name="mondayclosingtime" class="form-control monday" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="form-group mt-4-c">
        <div class="form-check">
          <input type="checkbox" name="hours[]" class="form-check-input filled-in" value="1" id="monday">
          <label class="form-check-label">24 Hours</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="form-group mt-4-c">
        <div class="form-check">
          <input type="checkbox" name="closed[]" class="form-check-input filled-in" value="1" id="mon_c">
          <label class="form-check-label">Closed</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


  </div>
  <div class='row'>

    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Tuesday Open</label>
        <input type="time" name="tuesdayopentime" class="form-control tuesday" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Tuesday Close</label>
        <input type="time" name="tuesdayclosingtime" class="form-control tuesday" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3 mt-4-c">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="form-check">
          <input type="checkbox" name="hours[]" class="form-check-input filled-in" value="2" id="tuesday">
          <label class="form-check-label">24 Hours</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3 mt-4-c">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="form-check">
          <input type="checkbox" name="closed[]" class="form-check-input filled-in" value="2" id="tue_c">
          <label class="form-check-label">Closed</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


  </div>
  <div class='row'>

    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Wednesday Open</label>
        <input type="time" name="wednesdayopentime" class="form-control wednesday" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Wednesday Close</label>
        <input type="time" name="wednesdayclosingtime" class="form-control wednesday" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3 mt-4-c">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="form-check">
          <input type="checkbox" name="hours[]" class="form-check-input filled-in" value="3" id="wednesday">
          <label class="form-check-label">24 Hours</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3 mt-4-c">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="form-check">
          <input type="checkbox" name="closed[]" class="form-check-input filled-in" value="3" id="wed_c">
          <label class="form-check-label">Closed</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


  </div>
  <div class='row'>

    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Thursday Open</label>
        <input type="time" name="thursdayopentime" class="form-control thursday" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Thursday Close</label>
        <input type="time" name="thursdayclosingtime" class="form-control thursday" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3 mt-4-c">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="form-check">
          <input type="checkbox" name="hours[]" class="form-check-input filled-in" value="4" id="thursday">
          <label class="form-check-label">24 Hours</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3 mt-4-c">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="form-check">
          <input type="checkbox" name="closed[]" class="form-check-input filled-in" value="4" id="thurs_c">
          <label class="form-check-label">Closed</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


  </div>
  <div class='row'>

    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Friday Open</label>
        <input type="time" name="fridayopentime" class="form-control friday" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Friday Close</label>
        <input type="time" name="fridayclosingtime" class="form-control friday" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3 mt-4-c">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="form-check">
          <input type="checkbox" name="hours[]" class="form-check-input filled-in" value="5" id="friday">
          <label class="form-check-label">24 Hours</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3 mt-4-c">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="form-check">
          <input type="checkbox" name="closed[]" class="form-check-input filled-in" value="5" id="fri_c">
          <label class="form-check-label">Closed</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


  </div>
  <div class='row'>

    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Saturday Open</label>
        <input type="time" name="saturdayopentime" class="form-control saturday" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Saturday Close</label>
        <input type="time" name="saturdayclosingtime" class="form-control saturday" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3 mt-4-c">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="form-check">
          <input type="checkbox" name="hours[]" class="form-check-input filled-in" value="6" id="saturday">
          <label class="form-check-label">24 Hours</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3 mt-4-c">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="form-check">
          <input type="checkbox" name="closed[]" class="form-check-input filled-in" value="6" id="sat_c">
          <label class="form-check-label">Closed</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


  </div>
  <div class='row'>

    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Sunday Open</label>
        <input type="time" name="sundayopentime" class="form-control sunday" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Sunday Close</label>
        <input type="time" name="sundayclosingtime" class="form-control sunday" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3 mt-4-c">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="form-check">
          <input type="checkbox" name="hours[]" class="form-check-input filled-in" value="7" id="sunday">
          <label class="form-check-label">24 Hours</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3 mt-4-c">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="form-check">
          <input type="checkbox" name="closed[]" class="form-check-input filled-in" value="7" id="sun_c">
          <label class="form-check-label">Closed</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


  </div>

</div>
```

How can i make sure that if user select Monday Open time as 9 Am then in Monday close time option it must be greater than 9 AM using jquery?

i want to implement the solution in Jquery.

Thanks

Comment: Show us what you have tried. SO isn't a free code writing service. The objective here is for you to post your attempts to solve your own issue and others help when they don't work as expected. See [ask] and [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like the following but obviously your implementation would be slightly different:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label>Monday Open</label>
<input type="time" name="mondayopentime" class="form-control monday"/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="myFunc()"/>
</div>
<script>
function myFunc(){
var value = $('.monday').val();
var num = timeStringToFloat(value)
if(num > 9){
console.log("Time should be before 9")
}else{
console.log("OK");
}
    
}
function timeStringToFloat(time) {
var hoursMinutes = time.split(/[.:]/);
var hours = parseInt(hoursMinutes[0], 10);
var minutes = hoursMinutes[1] ? parseInt(hoursMinutes[1], 10) : 0;
return hours + minutes / 60;
}
</script>
```